# Video conversion to AVI

Tags: video, vlc, codecs, handbrake, avi

I'd like to convert my video files on  Linux because my TV only recognizes the AVI video format.
My first attempt to convert my files was through Handbrake. The fact is that, out of the box, I only got two codecs, MPEG-4 and Matroska, I tried both and they don't work on my TV :(
I've tried to rename the destination file to a *.avi, but using the mediainfo tool, I get an error (I forgot to copy it) that basically says "it is a MP4 hidden in AVI file". I just had to rename the file to not have this error anymore. So there is no codec for Handbrake.
I also tried to convert my videos using VLC, but the codec isn't there too:
[Not the right codecs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQHBi.png)
Now I'm definitely sure this is not a bug, so how can I install the AVI codec on linux ?
Thanks in advance,
Mathematix

NOTA BENE: I'm French so it is possible that some answers may look strange :)

Comment: Try FFmpeg. Hopefully, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching through the internet I finally found the answer to my question. This might not be helpful for you because you may not have the same TV. Here's a bash script that I use to automatically convert my files : https://pastebin.com/ZGhKBqNj
If you want to add subtitles to your video file, just rename the file with the name of the video file.srt . The first argument is the video file and the second is the location (do not put the file name in the location). This is a fork of someone's script on Github but I don't remember his name... Hope this can help someone ! (Works on a Sony Bravia TV)

Answer (score 0):

AVI is a container for media files, not a codec itself. If your TV does not recognize the mp4 format, then it is due to missing codecs in your TV.

I would give a try convert the file using **Avidemux** and choose **mpeg2** codec for video and **mp2** for audio. For a trial simple short video will be enough.

Of course you can experiment with different codecs in the Avidemux.

Comment: Thanks! Avidemux doesn't suit me, so I'm looking forward to use ffmpeg... First of all, here's the result of the mediainfo command to one video file that works on my TV: https://pastebin.com/yZE10mua . I've got to use libxvid video codec and mp2 audio codec. I've made a lot of tests, but I really struggle with ffmpeg. Indeed, I've got a big lose of quality (here's the most relevant command: ffmpeg -i 3.mkv -c:a mp2 -c:v libxvid output.avi) (I've done some of my tests with a small .mkv file created with OBS...). I've also noticed this is not the quite same infos (https://pastebin.com/WtvqXztN).